# Functionality of ManualResetEvent.WaitOne with 0 time out argument

Tags: c#, manualresetevent, interrupted-exception, waitone

I was dealing with code that has some calls to `ManualResetEvent`'s [WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85bbbxt9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call.

From the MSDN documentation,

> If timeout is zero, the method does not block. It tests the state of the wait handle and returns immediately.

Now, this is my piece of code:

```
   Console.WriteLine("abc");
   if (manualResetEventObject.WaitOne(0, false))
       return;

   Console.WriteLine("def");
   //More function calls
```

Here, based on the doc, I'd expect it to print abc, *return from WaitOne* and print def. `manualResetEventObject` is not signaled at this point, and so `WaitOne`'s return value should be false.

However, def is never printed and I see a `ThreadInterruptedException` being thrown (there's a `try`/`catch` block enclosing this).

I don't understand why this doesn't print def or why the exception is thrown. What exactly is going on here ?

Comment: Looks like another thread has [interrupted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your thread before the call to `WaitOne()`.

Comment: I am curious why you need this overloaded waitone vs the general waitone (timespan) or waitone with int.  Are you switching contexts? Also the ThreadInteruptedException is not part of the exceptions thrown by the waitone method you are using.